# TeXstudio 2.12.16 (git 2.12.16)

Tags: texstudio

bonjour chers tous j'aimerais utiliser le package ulthese pour la rédaction de ma thèse. En suivant la procédure d'installation comme dans le guide ulthese un message d’alerte se produit "pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ulthese".tex impossible".
merci de m'apporter un éclairage.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please ask your question in english as this is an internatonal site. If you can't, you can ask it on french tex forums e.g. [texnique.fr](https://texnique.fr/osqa/)

Comment: Just in case: Was you TeX distribution  installed  *before* TeXstudio?